# Polygon contains polygon [MONGODB]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My issue is the following. I have a collection (territories) that have a geometry of type Polygon inside. The thing is that the polygons in my applications must be validated against this collection. Meaning that for a polygon to be valid, it must be COMPLETELY contained in at least one territory.

As `$geoWithin` is intented to work only in one direction. I try to do the following.

```
db.territories.insertMany([
   {
     _id: 1,
     geometry: {
       type: "Polygon",
       coordinates: [
         [
            [0, 0],
            [5, 0],
            [5, 5],
            [0, 5],
            [0, 0]
         ]
       ]
     }
   }
])

const aggregation = [
  {
    $addFields: {
      polygonToValidate: {
          type: "Polygon",
          coordinates: [[[2, 2], [4, 2], [4, 4], [2, 4], [2, 2]]]
      },
      territoryPolygon: "$geometry",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      polygonToValidate: {
        $geoWithin: {
          $geometry: "$territoryPolygon"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

db.territories.aggregate(aggregation);
```

The polygon is valid as it is completely contained inside the territory polygon. But is not posible to reference the document field, neither the field added in the `$addFields` (territoryPolygon).

Comment: I think you need a 3rd party library, e.g. [turfjs](https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanWithin)

Comment: Yeah i thought of that. But still. Is this possible at the db level?

Comment: The problem with turf is that i will have to fetch all territories. Having a multipolygon.

Comment: Use [$geoIntersects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) to get documents that at least partially overlap with your polygon, then filter them on application level.

Comment: @AlexBlex 's answer seems to be the best workaround for now. Thanks!